# My company enforces SSL mail encryption but makes us trust self-signed cert - is this wrong?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, email-client

When connecting to the mail server via the email client, we are forced to use SSL. Yet, we only have a self-signed certificate which the IT dept wants us to trust.

What are the real security repercussions?

Comment: If you can trust your company as a certificate authority, there are no risks. Yet, they are the endpoint and they can do whatever they want with the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the root key doesn't leak, which would break down the whole company CA system, the only issue specific to *this use* of a self signed certificate is distribution; a certificate authority certificate is normally already on any computer that needs a connection to the server, while this certificate needs to be distributed manually.

If a new computer needs a connection to the server and does not have the certificate, there is *no real security* if you connect anyway and just accept the certificate. For it to be of any use, it needs to *already exist on the computer*.

Comment: So if I have a laptop and connect it for the first time inside of the company network and trust the cert with the first connection, I won't get such prompts outside the company premises anymore. Is that considered safe then?

Comment: @Monolith Yes, that would be as safe as your company network (that is, someone inside the company could feed you a fake cert, but that may be a risk worth taking) The problem is, the first time someone forgets to do it locally and is travelling needing mail access, waiting to get back to the office to press "ok" may not be very likely to happen. If you run Windows, pushing it out to all machines as a group policy may be an option, then it will be installed automatically when the machine is connected to the AD (normally at install time)

Answer (score 1):

Just as the other two have said, it basically relies on how much you trust your company, which is a factor anyway, so it's likely not a big deal (though they could easily get a free SSL certificate from startcom, so I have no idea why they would insist on a self-signed one).

But as Paul outlined with his example, it also matters if they have you install their own root certificate on your computer; if they don't and instead ask you to click through warning boxes each time, I would suggest speaking up, and emailing a link to this page to your company's IT department.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more complex question than it might appear. The short answer is that if they are following best practices with regard to protecting their self-signed root CA and deploying the root to client machines (incredibly important!) then there is no additional risk beyond that normally incurred with X509 PKI.

The longer answer is, as usual, "it depends what corners they cut". Here's a scenario under which the risk is higher...

> Your company does not install the self-signed root directly on
>   employee laptops. When asked about this oversight they say "that's a
>   real PITA in a heterogenous computing environment". This (depending on
>   client and other factors) forces you to choose to click "continue"
>   through an untrusted dialog each time you launch the client. Big deal
>   right? It's still encrypted. One day you're in Madrid, enjoying room
>   service in a five star hotel (as a rising star within the company you
>   get the poshest assignments) and you open your laptop up to get some
>   work done...
>
> You always connect to the VPN, but you left your mail client open last
>   time you put the laptop to sleep and it throws up the same annoying
>   warning it always shows when you open it. You swiftly click through
>   the dialog because you've been trained by your IT dept to do so. Sadly, 
>   this time it's a different cert. If you had inspected it directly (you
>   have a photographic memory and love doing comparisons of base64
>   encoded public keys) you wouldn't have clicked through, but you were
>   in a hurry and now the unscrupulous hotel manager running the hotel
>   capture portal knows your email login and password (p@ssw0rd1).
>
> Unfortunately, you use p@ssw0rd1 on all sorts of other websites, so
>   you find your reddit, amazon, and even stackoverflow accounts swiftly
>   compromised. Worse yet, your boss gets an email from "you" with an
>   obscene rant and notice of resignation. All because you clicked
>   through that innocuous dialog you've clicked through a thousand times
>   before.

This (unlikely) scenario is possible when blindly clicking through "untrusted cert" dialogs. Users can (hopefully) be trained to avoid this by telling them not to click through such dialogs and by adding the corporate CA to the trusted roots list of your OS/browser or using a trusted public CA.

Comment: Thanks for this little story. We (everyone using Macs) are told to add  the cert to trusted roots the first time we see it. So the prompt doesn't show up. So there is no immediate risk then?

Comment: Correct, if you have the root added (and the private key your IT dept created is being protected) your risk is no higher than a typical certificate.

Answer (score -1):

It's wrong if you are expected to do anything about it such as click dialog boxes accepting certificates.

If they are doing their job properly they should distribute the certificate internally such that all required network elements already trust it, e.g. browsers, mail user agents, applications, ...

In other words, if you know about it, it's wrong.